# Deleting the item from cascaded drop-down and list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I trying to delete the cascaded drop-down and list check-box ,that is item in the drop-down and its related check-box items  must be deleted when the button is clicked. Im not able to delete the selected item from the drop-down so please help me delete the desired item.

[link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vhbp7QNSz69Ibbzh9qtr)

html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Car Type">
  <ion-content ng-contorller="carBrand">
    <h3> Add/Edit the Car Types </h3>
    {{sample}}
    Make:
      <!--select name="client" ng-model="selectedRequest.continent" ng-options="c.name for c in brandList" required></select-->
      <select ng-model="carBrand" ng-options="make.name for make in brandList"></select>
     Type:
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="cartype" ng-repeat="brandType in carBrand.types" ng-disabled="!carBrand">
    <span>{{brandType}}</span>
    </ion-checkbox><br><br>
    <button ng-click="addEntry()">Edit</button>
    <button ng-click="home()">Back</button>
    <button ng-click="delete($index)">Delete</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller:

```
var carService =angular.module('carService', ['ionic']);
carService.controller('carBrand',['$scope',function($scope){

 $scope.brandList=[
 {'name':'Benz', 'types':['SUV', 'Sedan']},
 {'name':'BMW', 'types':['SUV', 'Sedan', 'Van']}
];

 $scope.remove=function(index){
   delete $scope.brandList[$index];
 };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `remove` is not correct

```
$scope.remove = function(){
   $scope.brandList.splice($scope.brandList.indexOf($scope.carBrand), 1);
   $scope.carBrand = {};
};
```

Also you don't have the same names on the HTML and controller `delete != remove`

```
<button ng-click="remove()">Delete</button>
```

And correct `ng-contorller` to `ng-controller`

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) allows you to change the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

Comment: will this help in deleting {name:Benz, types:['suv','seadan']} and can you please put it in plnkr so can understand it.

Comment: deletion of the item in drop-down and list is not happening @taguenizy

Comment: I want to delete something like this {'brand':'Benz', 'types':['Sedan','Suv']} ,so that drop-down and related items in list are also get deleted.And when i select other item in drop-down it not getting deleted instead it is deleting first item in the drop-down box. Can you please help me in this

Comment: @sree I've edited the answer and the plunker for you. [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2l4LE8oIVX5zFPTFPnhY)

Comment: now it is deleting the second item in the drop-down.On selecting 'benz' it is deleting 'bmw' in the drop-down. And also the check-box list is not getting deleted.

Comment: @sree updated. [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2l4LE8oIVX5zFPTFPnhY) the `ng-contorller` wasn't helping

Comment: It still the same and doesn't delete the specific item selected in the drop-down